# Eclipse is not recognizing Javadoc images properties in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Really new to java here...  I'm trying to embed Javadoc images in Eclipse.  I have the image stored in a "doc-files" folder inside the package that will reference it.  However when I add the following line:

```
<img src="doc-files/MyImage.png" width="250" alt="description">
```

Eclipse comes back saying "**The word 'src' is not correctly spelled**" and provides 5 fixes for it, none of which make sense.  Is one of my Javadocs core components missing?  My version of Eclipse is 4.9.0.  Many thanks.

Comment: Your HTML line displayed in your post does work in NetBeans but only if you create the **doc-files** directory (folder) directly within the directory that contains the source files (**.java** files) for your project application and then place your image files within that **doc-files** directory. This image will most likely not show within your IDE's JavaDoc display. Instead a generic image icon will be displayed. It will however be displayed within the actual JavaDoc viewed from your Web-Browser.

Comment: This should be a bug report with a patch rather than a Stack Overflow question here. _Add 'src'  to dictonary_ can be used as a workaround. By the way, you are using a pretty old Eclipse version. The current version is Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14).

Comment: I see, thank you both.  I'll look into perhaps switching IDE's or at least upgrading Eclipse...